# "come to see" (about the meeting place)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Why don’t you **come to see your friends** more often?

Does "come to see" mean to visit them on their place or not necessarily? Can it be somewhere outside, in a cafe or club?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It implies that the person saying this is in the same place as the friends, not the same place as "you" in this sentence. It can be somewhere outside though as you say, just in the general area of where your friends are.

For example, I live in Manchester and my friends live across London. Someone in London says "why don't you come to see your friends more often". "Come" implies "Come to London".

Comment: So it doesn't mean "come to London to their place". The meeting place in London can be different, right?

Comment: Yes, it can be different.

Comment: Could you answer please one more question? "come to see" and "go to see" in that sentence would be with the same meaning or not?

Comment: Similar. Because my friend lives in London (where they are telling me to go) "come to see" is appropriate. If they were somewhere else (but still telling me to go to London), "go to see" would be used.